# John Mueller infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite

I'm trying to figure out infinite scroll with history and pagination, as recommended by google, 
https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html

John Mueller's demo does exactly what I want, but I can't figure out how/where the data is being loaded.
http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items

I copied page source and js and css, but of course the source is for the particular "page" it happens to be on.
Everything just points to the /items directory and the page isn't being reloaded on new data, just the content area refreshed, so I don't get it.

Probably just being a noob, but any insight appreciated.

Comment: You have somewhere an callback that is being called when you're getting close to the end of the scroll, and new data is needed. You make an ajax call there, and add the newly received items to your list (in DOM). Please post your code, so we can help

Comment: I understand, but I don't see how/where the actual data is being retrieved.  The ajax call to /items?page=2 doesn't show me how the data is accessed and formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample page makes use of a service available at `http://scrollsample.appspot.com` using the complete URL `http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items?page=2&type=json` to get the specific data paginated in a return type of JSON.

You can past that url in a browser and see the raw data that is returned from the service.

The fact that the webpage is also hosted at the same base url is immaterial.  Once you add the parameters in question, you no longer get the HTML "website".  Instead you get a formatted data response (in this case JSON).

Comment: Thank you, it seems obvious now.  I missed the importance of the type=json parameter.

Comment: Ok, I'm closer but still stymied.
Does anyone possibly have a fully functional example with all source code for this?
I've tried to emulate what happens with the type=json parameter and have succeeded in getting one page load but nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

If you "View Source" you will see that they [reference a file of JavaScript](http://scrollsample.appspot.com/static/main.js)

In this file are the functions which implement the pagination.  For example, in the `loadFollowing()` function you will see a call to `$.getJSON()` which fetches JSON data via AJAX.  It then calls a function `showFollowing()` which adds the content (which came in the JSON data) to the page with: `$('div.listitempage:last').after(data.response);`

Answer (score 0):

The data is being loaded from 
'http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items?page=2&type=json'
when you start the page, then the function primeCache() is called and populate 'next_data_cache' var.

When you scrool the page, other function is called, this time is 'showFollowing()' who get the data doing a getJSON and passing data again to 'next_data_cache' var.

Comment: I get that much [sort of], but I don't see where the data is coming from.
getJSON is using same url /items&page=some number but nowhere do I see where the actual data is being  retrieved.

The sample sites says "This is a list of items from last.fm's GetHypedTracks", but I find no reference to that data.

Comment: @twiddy, see my answer for the code that retrieves the data

Comment: @twiddly probably http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items?page=2&type=json has a server side code who is doing the request to 'last.fm', so you will get only the result, not the code and the address where the data is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

I see this in their code:

```
$.getJSON(next_data_url, function(data) {
    showFollowing(data);
    is_loading = 0;
});
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.

Comment: Quote: "John Mueller's demo does exactly what I want, but I can't figure out how/where the data is being loaded"