# Autoload a new page at the end of the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to autoload a new page when the user reaches the bottom of a page?

eg: a user is browsing a.php When the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page a.php, the new page, say b.php loads automatically without refreshing the page (the url in the address bar also changes to b.php)

eg this page: http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/shimla/Uttarakhand-dissent-made-Congress-call-HP-meeting/articleshow/51679032.cms

When you scroll to the bottom of the article, the new article is loaded and also the url of page in the address bar changes to the new article's url

Comment: on the basis that youve found an example, then yes, there is a way to do it.  You need to some further research to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with PHP + jQuery + AJAX but it's not as easy as you might think if you need to care about SEO. Take a look at what [Google says](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html) about SEO-friendly infinite-scrolling. Take a look at [John Muller's demo](http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items). More about it [in this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884671/john-mueller-infinite-scroll).

Plugins that'll help you start:

- [jScroll](https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll)
- [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html)
- [Infinite AJAX Scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) (paid)
- [jQuery Endless Scroll](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll) (abandoned)
- [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) (abandoned)

PS. Remember that [Infinite Scrolling is NOT for every website](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/infinite-scrolling/)!